# How to trigger js function inside php?

Tags: javascript, php

```
if (!$errors) {
 //Call Js function without any events
 }
```

I want to call js function once inside if came,How to call js function inside if condition?Is it possible to call js fucntion without any events inside php tag?

Comment: `PHP` is a server side language, `Javascript` - client side. You need to send some data from server to client,

Comment: if you don't mind,plz explain me with some example

Comment: The answer is: you can't. If you explain your purpose maybe we can point you to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery:

```
if (!$errors) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  myfunction();
              });
          </script>";
}
```

Comment: geethasj1 sj did no mentioned jquery

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
if (!$errors) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  myfunction();
              });
          </script>";
}
```

without jquery and wait unlit whole page is loaded

```
if (!$errors) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload = function() {
        myfunction();
     };
    </script>";
}
```

and without Onload

```
if (!$errors) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>myfunction();</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way :

```
<?php
// php code
```

if(condition){

```
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jsFunction();
</script>

<?php
```

}

```
// php code
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just make an echo and call it between two script tags.

Like :

```
if (!$errors) {
  echo "<script> myfunction(); </script>";
 }
```